# Proving: If a function is bounded, then the fuction's limit is bounded.

Tags: limits, functions

The question I have to answer is the following:

Let I be an open interval that contains the point c and suppose that f is a function that is defined on I except possibly at the point c. If $m \le f(x) \le M$ for all $x \in I\setminus \{c\}$ and $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$, then $m \le L \le M$.

Using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit of a function, my initial thought was to prove this using contradiction. That is, to assume that $L<m$ or $L>M$ and to arrive at a contradiction. I am having trouble thinking of a way to get a contradiction. If anyone can help steer me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 3):

I often find proof by contradiction to be expedient, but have a preference for
a 'constructive' approach, which often lends more intuition.

Suppose $f(x) \in [m,M]$ for all $x \in I \setminus \{c\}$ and $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$.

By definition, for all $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if
$0<|x-c|<\delta$ then $|L-f(x) | < \epsilon$. Since $f(x) \in [m,M]$, we have
$m-\epsilon < L < M +\epsilon$.

Since this is true for any $\epsilon>0$, we have $m \le L \le M$.